# using row data for column headers

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have a table

```
  CREATE TABLE "AUTOMATION"."TESTRESULTS" 
   (
    "BUILDNUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "TESTNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
   )
```

sample data would be

```
    buildnumber  testname   statusid
    1            testname1  pass 
    1            testname2  fail
    1            testname3  warning     
    2            testname1  fail
    2            testname2  fail
    2            testname3  fail
    3            testname1  fail
    3            testname2  pass
    3            testname3  fail
```

I would like to get a query to output:

```
               3         2           1
testname1      fail      fail        pass
testname2      pass      fail        fail 
testname3      fail      fail        warning
```

What is the best approach to getting this output (buildnumbers as columns)?  I am using Oracle 11g and the test names are not known at the time of building the report.

Answer (score 3):

11g has the pivot construct, which appears to meet your needs:

```
with pivot_data as (
select buildnumber, testname, status
  from testresults)
select * from pivot_data
 pivot (min(status)
        for buildnumber
        in ('1' as build_1, '2' as build_2, '3' as build_3)
        )
order by 1;
```

Note the min(status), the pivot requires an aggregate function, so we're working around that requirement.

```
TESTNAME    BUILD_1 BUILD_2 BUILD_3
testname1   pass    fail    fail
testname2   fail    fail    pass
testname3   warning fail    fail
```